# how to format php email

Tags: php, email

I will make it really simple. I want to send an email by php. now here is code.

```
$line = '\n';
$a = "Customer Phone: ";
$b = "Customer Last Name: ";
$message = $a.$number.$line.$b.$LastName;       

$to = "forgotten_tarek@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Umrah Booking";
$from = $mailer;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

here is the output:

```
Customer Phone: 0712345678\nCustomer Last Name: Showkot
```

and the email is showing no sender. It says `nobody`.

I want the email to be look like:

```
Customer Phone: 0712345678
Customer Last Name: Showkot
```

and I also want to show that the email is from `example@example.com`

Answer (score 7):

1) Change `'\n'` to `"\n"`. Special characters (such as `\n`) are interpreted only in [double-quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

2) Try to change `"From:"` to `"From: "`. Or, perhaps, variable `$from` has no value.

Comment: +1 for explaining _why_ and not just _what_ to do. I was about to comment about _why_ different quotes were necessary, but then you just added that.

Comment: Thank You... I just logged in to say that the problem is solved!! anyway thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a html mail also., in that you can send a mail which is actually formatted using html.. this is very simple and yu can almost use all tags which yu use to format content in html and even css can be added..!! you need to add headers to send html mail.

here is a example..!

```
$to = "sended@test.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$a = "Customer Phone: ";
$b = "Customer Last Name: ";
$message = $a.$number.$line.$b.$LastName;  
$message="
<html>
<body>
  <h1>$a</h1>: $number <br> <h1>$b</h1>: $LastName<br>
</body>
</html>";

$from = "tester@test.com";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

try this too., it will work..! :)

Comment: Thank you It already worked!! I have processed it :-) but thank you anyway for your concern!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$line = "\n";
$a = "Customer Phone: ";
$b = "Customer Last Name: ";
$message = $a.$number.$line.$b.$LastName;

$to = "forgotten_tarek@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Umrah Booking";
$from = $mailer;
$headers = "From: " . $from. "\r\n".
'Reply-To: '. $from . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter html in the message tag for example:

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```