# Add a button to email text to a) auto-reply, or b) go to a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, email

OK, I think this is a pretty easy one but I'm mostly just digging up auto-responder results from Google. All I'm looking to do is add two types of buttons to the text of an email (in Gmail, preferably). Here's how they would work:

> *Hello,*
>
> *Please tap on your favourite fruit:*
>
> *[Bananas] [Persimmon]*
>
> *Great! If you want to learn more about fruits and vegetables, click here:*
>
> *[Find out more]*

I want the first buttons to just send me a reply that says "Bananas" or "Persimmon" depending on which button the email recipient presses. And the second button should just act as any normal link.

EDIT:

Here's what I've got so far:

1. Add an inline image to a Gmail message
2. Select the message and add a link
3. For the fruit options, make the link mailto:myname@domain.com?subject=FruitName
4. For the "Find out more," just make a link as usual

It's not ideal because "mailto" just opens a "compose email" window for the recipient with some info filled in (*to:* address, subject) as opposed to directly sending an email, but it's a workable solution for now.

Comment: Just wondering if you're looking for something like - `<a href="mailto:bla@bla.com?subject=bla">link</a>`? it works with desktop email client, not sure on web mail.

Comment: You can't send emails with javascript only, but you can open the local email client with a pre-populated subject and body. The `mailto:` @Pangloss mentioned above

Comment: @Pangloss  Thanks for the comment. It looks like raw HTML isn't supported in Gmail. Does this mean the email has to be sent from elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know any further answers, not an expert on that field.

Comment: @Rogare in the response mail, how did you identify the user who replied. Assuming you send this mail to multiple users and some replyed with Bananas and other with Persimmon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to try `mailto` maybe?

```
 <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">
    <button>Bananas</button>
 </a>
 <a href="https://www.actasnormalLink.com">
    <button>Persimmon</button>
 </a>
```

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe JavaScript only doesn't send emails!

if you use php then you can format the [emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238997/how-to-format-php-email) the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated. If I need to send the email from a Gmail address, how would I use this code?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/487495/how-to-make-mailto-links-open-in-gmail-instead-of-outlook i think it all depends on the settings of the client's pc so all you have to do is set up the mailto:usingyourownemail@gmail.com

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I've managed to use your approach in Gmail by just added the links directly to inline Gmail images and then adding `?subject=Persimmon` to the mailto line. It's not quite ideal because it doesn't actually send the email, but it might be the best option from within Gmail. Thanks again.